# Remove or hide SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Is it possible to remove or hide an SVG element using CSS or jQuery?

I know how to "edit" div elements using CSS. Something like this:

```
div[style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 207px; height: 95px; left: 513px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I am curious whether something like that is possible with SVG.

Code example for SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 207 95" xml:space="preserve" height="95px" viewBox="0 0 207 95" width="207px" version="1.1" y="0px" x="0px">
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the SVG `visibility` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility

> The visibility attribute lets you control the visibility of graphical elements. With a value of hidden or collapse the current graphics element is invisible

---

[**update**]

However `display: none;` and `opacity: 0` work too.

But know that `opacity` ([MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity)) is the most computationally expensive (as it keeps the elements click event alive even though the element isn't displayed visually),

then `visibility`,

then `display`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/display.

But rushing to use `display` isn't always the best because we get more control over the elements with `visibility` (i.e., "If you are trying to hide an entire group, except for one particular member of that group, use 'visibility' as it is overrideable in inheritance." [link](http://svg-whiz.com/svg/HideShow.svg))

[**SVG Resource**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)