# Best practice to hide a svg element

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I do have many (>100) SVG-`<g>`-elements on my screen, and if the user hovers over one of them, inner img-elements included in this `<g>` should become visible. If the user hovers out of the `<g>`, they should turn invisible again.

I see there are two ways of doing this:

1. Insert the `<img>` on every mouseenter and remove it on mouseleave.
2. Insert the elements on every `<g>` during the initial rendering, make them initially invisible and turn them visible on mouseenter.

Which one is the way to go? 
If it is #2, whats the CSS property to use? I found many, including

```
visibility : hidden;
```

and

```
display : none;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility :) Related ! For your case i recommend `display:none` .. It should be quicker with more elements.

Comment: Display none will hide the element and the placeholder for it. So check out the performance on that

Comment: Definitely solution #2

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578837/remove-or-hide-svg-element

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that they doesn't work in the same way,

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Conserve the space that the object is using, so if your object size is
for example: Width: 250px, Height:200px, will show a blank space.

By the other hand:

```
display:none;
```

won't show the blank space, your object still be there but at Width:0px Height:0px

Bye!

Comment: This is wrong.  There is no "conservation of space" in SVG. That's an HTML thing.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_visibility this is an example of visibility, probably doesn't work in the same way with svg, usually you can't add some css properties to SVG tags like <path>, instead use svg properties to do that

Comment: OP is talking about SVG elements (elements inside an SVG).  The behaviour of SVG elements is different from HTML.

Comment: If you want the blank space you might need a container that reserves the space that you need and then you could hide your SVG element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility

Answer (score 0):

Either will do.  There is not effective difference between them when it comes to SVG.

There is one exception, and that is when they are used with `<tspan>` elements.  If a `<tspan>` is `visibility: hidden` it will leave a gap.  But it will be completely ignored with `dispay: none`.

For every other use, the behaviour will be the same, and you can use either.